# Making a client in Qt that tries to connect to server, and if it fails, it keeps trying until it connects

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket

I'm using `QTcpSocket` for this program.

```
void MainWindow::connectFunction()
{

    socket->connectToHost(ip, port);
    if(socket->waitForConnected(2000))
    {   
        QTime time = QTime().currentTime();

        ui->textBrowser->append('[' + time.toString("h:m") + "] Connection successful.");
    }
    else
    {
        QTime time = QTime().currentTime();
        ui->textBrowser->append('[' + time.toString("h:m") + "] Connection failed. Retrying...");
        connectFunction();
    }

}
```

I attempt to connect to the server with `ui->connectToHost(ip, port)`. If the connection fails, I call `connectFunction()` again to restart the connecting process. It should do this until the connection is successful. The problem arises when I call `connectFunction()`. This crashes the program, and I don't know why. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `connectFunction` recursively and if the connection fails for many iterations, then you would encounter an stack-overflow error. One alternate solution is to have `connectFunction` as a slot and call it in a queued way to prevent recursion:

```
void MainWindow::connectFunction()
{

    socket->connectToHost(ip, port);
    if(socket->waitForConnected(2000))
    {   
        QTime time = QTime().currentTime();

        ui->textBrowser->append('[' + time.toString("h:m") + "] Connection successful.");
    }
    else
    {
        QTime time = QTime().currentTime();
        ui->textBrowser->append('[' + time.toString("h:m") + "] Connection failed. Retrying...");
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "connectFunction", Qt::QueuedConnection );
    }
}
```

There are other possible solutions like implementing it in an asynchronous way and starting a timer which invokes connecting periodically when an error is occurred.

Comment: How about a simple old-fashioned while loop?!

Comment: @HamishMoffatt a while loop blocks the event loop and makes GUI unresponsive if it is in the main thread.

Comment: @Nejat Doesn't `waitForConnected(2000)` do the same?

Comment: @thuga You are right, that does the same. But in a synchronous manner calling with a queued connection is better than having a while loop. Because it lets other events be processed periodically. After all an asynchronous approach is better if it is running in the main thread.